# On clicking a link use link's ID to find div with specific class that is the same as ID from that link that Is kept in an array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an array that is storing ID's taken from Anchor links and applying them to specific divs. I need the link whose ID has been applied to the div through the array to when clicked open that specific div which is working as an overlay/modal. I am stuck as I am trying to use:

```js
$('[id^="overlay-box-"]').click(function(){
    if ($('.overlay-box').hasClass($this)) {
        $('.overlay-box').fadeIn('slow');
    }
})
```

Which does not work.

The Html is:

```html
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-one"></a>
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-two"></a>
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-three"></a>
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-four"></a>
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-five"></a>
```

These ID's are stored in an array. and applied to div's with this class:

```html
<div class="overlay-box"></div>
<div class="overlay-box"></div>
<div class="overlay-box"></div>
<div class="overlay-box"></div>
<div class="overlay-box"></div>
```

So they output on page load as:

```html
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-one"></div>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-two"></div>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-three"></div>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-four"></div>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-five"></div>
```

the css is

```css
// Overlay Box

.overlay-box {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
}

.overlay-box {
    width: 100vw;
    height:100vh;
    //position:absolute;
    //top: 0%;
    //left: 0%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 10000;
    overflow:visible;
    backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    -o-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    -ms-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    -moz-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
}
```

As previously stated the issue I am having is writing the Jquery/JS to once one of the anchor links above are clicked to fade in the specific div the anchor link relates to.

My JS at the moment is:

```js
var overlayarray = $('.overlay-open').map(function(i) {
    return this.id;
});

$( ".overlay-box" ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).addClass(overlayarray[index]);
});

$('[id^="overlay-box-"]').click(function(){
    if ($('.overlay-box').hasClass($this)) {
        $('.overlay-box').fadeIn('slow');
    }
})
```

Last part does not work I know.

I have also tried this

```js
$('.overlay-open').click(function(){

    $(this).each(function (i) {

        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');

        if ($('.overlay-box').hasClass(currentId)) {

            $('.overlay-box').fadeIn('slow');
        }

    });
    
});
```

Does not work also and when I use the below, it opens all divs

```js
$('[id^="overlay-box-"]').click(function(){
    
    $('.overlay-box').fadeIn('slow');
    
});
```

Comment: `if ('.overlay-box'.hasClass($this) ) {` <= all kinds of syntax problems here.  A string does not have a `hasClass` method.

Comment: to add to @Taplar's comment, `if ('.overlay-box'.hasClass($this) ) {` to `if ($('.overlay-box').hasClass($this) ) {`.                            for future reference, considering this is just Html + css + js, you may to want to consider including a code sample. it will guarentee more answers as it's easier to debug

Comment: Yes, I know hence the question asking what am I doing incorrect with the code..... I have provided all that is necessary, the a links, the divs and the JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

You do your selection with CSS directly inside  `document.querySelector(".overlay-box." + a.id)` , where you extract  id of clicked link, and use it in selector:

when you click link with id:

```
overlay-box-three
```

use that, then search for element with classes: `.overlay-box.overlay-box-three`

**EXAMPLE** using `document.querySelector`:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("a.overlay-open")].forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector(".overlay-box." + a.id).style.display = "block";
    console.clear();
    console.log(a.id)
  })
});
```

```css
.overlay-box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-one">overlay-box overlay-box-one</div>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-two">overlay-box overlay-box-two</div>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-three">overlay-box overlay-box-three</div>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-four">overlay-box overlay-box-four</div>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-five">overlay-box overlay-box-five</div>


<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-one">overlay-box-one</a>
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-two">overlay-box-two</a>
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-three">overlay-box-three</a>
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-four">overlay-box-four</a>
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-five">overlay-box-five</a>
```

And to fix you last attempt using jquery:

```
$('[id^="overlay-box-"]').click(function(event){
    $('.overlay-box.'+this.id).fadeIn()
});
```

Take note we passed event on click with `.click(function(event)`  so we can later use `this.id` to get id of clicked element and use it selector.

```js
$('[id^="overlay-box-"]').click(function(event) {
  $('.overlay-box.' + this.id).fadeIn()
});
```

```css
.overlay-box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-one">overlay-box overlay-box-one</div>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-two">overlay-box overlay-box-two</div>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-three">overlay-box overlay-box-three</div>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-four">overlay-box overlay-box-four</div>
<div class="overlay-box overlay-box-five">overlay-box overlay-box-five</div>


<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-one">overlay-box-one</a>
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-two">overlay-box-two</a>
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-three">overlay-box-three</a>
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-four">overlay-box-four</a>
<a class="overlay-open" href="#" id="overlay-box-five">overlay-box-five</a>
```